# Can I use nodemailer in a vue.js Component? I have Firebase as a backend

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nodemailer

I'm trying to do something like this inside my contact-form.vue component.
Is it possible to make it work from the front-end?

```
async mail(){
                let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                    host: 'smtp.mailgun.org',
                    port: 587,
                    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
                    auth: {
                        user: "postmaster@sandbox9324.mailgun.org", // generated ethereal user
                        pass: "29a6af3f71fbdf" // generated ethereal password
                    }
                });
                let info = await transporter.sendMail({
                    from: '"Fred Foo " <noreply@meso.com>', // sender address
                    to: 'a.skarmintzos@gmail.com', // list of receivers
                    subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
                    text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
                    html: '<b>Hello world?</b>' // html body
                });
                console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);

                console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info))
            }
```

Comment: Not likely to be possible in the way that you are now since the browser will not be able to make outgoing SMTP connections.

Comment: Thanks, Ill go with the Firebase functions solutions. 
[link](https://medium.com/@edigleyssonsilva/cloud-functions-for-firebase-sending-e-mail-1f2631d1022e)